# Segmentation Fault while initializing array in C

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I am a very beginner in C. I went through the existing questions but could not understand because they involved strings and characters. Here is my little part of my code:

```
#define grid 32

int main (void)
{
int NU, NV, NP;
NU=(grid-1)*grid;
NV=grid*(grid-1);
NP=grid*grid;
double u[NU], uc[NU];
double v[NV], vc[NV];
double p[NP], pc[NP];

//Initialization


// Initializing u

    for (i=0; i<(grid-1); i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<(grid); j++)
        {
            int k=j*grid+i;

            if (j==(grid-1))
            {
            u[k]=1.0;
            }
            else if (j==(grid-2) && i>0 && i<(grid-2))
            {
            u[k]=1.0;
            }
            else
            {
            u[k]=0.0;
            }
        }
    }


// Initializing v
for (j=0; j<(grid-1); j++)
{
    for (i=0; i<grid; i++)
    {
        int k=j*grid+i;
        v[k]=0.0;
    }
}

// Initializing p
for (j=0; j<grid; j++)
{
    for (i=0; i<grid; i++)
    {
        int k=j*grid+i;
        p[k]=1.0;
    }
}
```

I am trying to initialize these arrays but instead getting segmentation fault.
Kindly help me with this.

Comment: I need to see the arrays initialization code.

Comment: Why not: `int NU = (grid-1) * grid;` and `int NV = grid * (grid-1);` and `int NP = grid * grid;`, with each variable initialized as it is created?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Tried, still the same problem.

Comment: Oh - sorry; it is stylistic issue, not a source of your crash. Are you in a limited environment of any sort (embedded system, ...)?  You've created 48 KiB of arrays, which shouldn't stress most systems these days.  How do you know it is these initializations that crash?  Have you put `printf()` statements between the sets of loops so you know which one is crashing?  (Make sure the format string ends with a newline each time.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
int k=j*grid+i;
```

Its taking your array index out of bounds. When you access `u[k]` then you get a seg fault. Also, there is no need to use 2 loops to initialize a single dimensional array unless there is a specific logic you are trying to implement here which i am not aware of.

Comment: More specifically, it was meant to be `int k = j*(grid-1) + i;` . Same problem in a few other places.

Answer (score 1):

You defined

```
NU=(grid-1)*grid;
NV=grid*(grid-1);
NP=grid*grid;
```

Now let's see how far you are accesing the array elements in the loop.

```
for (i=0; i<(grid-1); i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<(grid); j++)
    {
        int k=j*grid+i; // so in the max case k = (grid-1)*grid+grid-2 = grid*grid+2
        ...             // and it is larger than NU so it will be accessing wrong memory
                        // memory region
    }
}
```

Follow the same anlysis to make sure other array initialization does not exceed the boundary.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason array initialization can result in a SEGFALT is by reading or writing to an element which does not exist.

The most common way to accomplish this is by using an index beyond the bounds of the array.  In C, the lowest element is index `0` (zero) and the highest is `N-1` where `N` is the number of elements declared for the array.

```
int  array [5000];

array [-1] = 0;   /* BAD */
array [5000] = 0;   /* BAD */
```

Both of these are invalid accesses.  They might SEGFAULT.  They might change another variable's value.  They might seem to do nothing.  Or they might seem to work.

Comment: As far as I can see, I have clearly defined the arrays and initializing only the defined arrays. There should be no ambiguity.

Comment: @TanmayAgrawal:  The code is far from clear.  The declarations are the most clear, but the initialization logic is hard to follow.

Comment: Let me make it more clear. I want P to be a grid*grid array with all values equal to 1. Array V would be a grid*(grid-1) dimensional with all values 0. Array u would be (grid-1)*grid dimensional with all the (j==(grid-1)) i.e. topmost y-direction to be equal to one, (j==(grid-2) && i>0 && i<(grid-2)) i.e. one unit lower than than the topmost also equal to one and the rest to be zero.